# MySQL gives error "SSL connection error: Unable to get private key"

Tags: mysql, ssl

I keep getting the errors "SSL connection error: Unable to get private key" when using mysql client.

In order to get it to work, I have change the permission 444. However, I would like to lock it down to whatever user/group the client runs on.

MySQL is installed on AWS Linux. Thank.

Comment: What user are you running the mysql client as, and what user is the key owned by?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it works fine. I am running as the default user and have changed the permission to that of user I am running as.

So the mysql client runs as that particular.